# Row is not visible in SSRS whereas it should be. Why?

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting a strange issue with my SSRS report. A row is not visible in my report whereas its data is added in the sum total of the data.
I have 2 records of different date. Both are same just their dates are different. When I see both records individually for each date then I can see those records but if I put my date parameters so as to show both records together then only one record is visible whereas the total of amount is of both records.
How is this possible that a row is not visible when it should be?

**In this the data is for one date (date received parameter and column)** 
[image: In this the data is for one date (date received parameter and column)]

**In this the data is for second date (date received parameter and column column)**
[image: In this the data is for second date (date received parameter and column column)]

**In this image data is for both dates (date received parameter) but only one row with amount $181.8 is visible whereas in total amount it is added i.e. (181.8+181.8 - 24.0 =339.60)**
[image: In this image data is for both dates (date received parameter) but only one row with amount $181.8 is visible whereas in total amount it is added i.e. (181.8+181.8 - 24.0 =339.60)]

I want that all the data should be visible.. the total is right. Why is it not visible and how to do it right?

No sorting or filters are put in the report.

Comment: Are you grouping the data?

Comment: Ohh.. I now noticed.. I have not grouped any data but In the detailed group two fields were not included which were creating this issue.. Thanks for getting my attention to the grouping.. I searched everything else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In detailed group some fields were missing which were creating this issue. I added all the fields in that and got what i needed.
No other grouping is done on my report.